# Tikz tree - text rotated 90 degrees on vertical lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I've been trying to make a probability tree, and I think I've almost got it looking quite nice, however the labels on the vertical lines going downwards are sloped with the line, resulting in the text being rotated 90 degrees. So my question is, can I have rotated labels, whilst also having some labels I've chosen to have a normal orientation?

```
usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}


% Define styles for bags and leafs
\tikzstyle{deck} = [text width=4em, text centered]
\tikzstyle{end} = [circle, minimum width=3pt,fill, inner sep=0pt]

% Set the overall layout of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=3.5cm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=3.5cm, sibling distance=2cm]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sloped]
\node[deck] {First card}
        child {
                node[deck] {Second card}
                child {
                        node[end, label=below: {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[above] {$\frac{1}{3}$}
                        node[below] {Q $\spadesuit$}
                }
                child {
                        node[end, label=below:  {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[left] {$\frac{1}{3}$}
                        node[right] {Q $\heartsuit$}
                }
                child {
                        node[end, label=below:  {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[above] {$\frac{1}{3}$}
                        node[below] {A $\heartsuit$}
        }
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$\frac{1}{4}$}
                node[below] {A $\spadesuit$}
        }
        child {
                node[deck] {Second card}
                child {
                        node[end, label=below:  {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[above] {$1$}
                        node[below] {A $\spadesuit$}
                }
                child {
                        node[end, label=below:  {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[above] {$0$}
                        node[below] {$\neg$A $\spadesuit$}
        }
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$\frac{1}{4}$}
                node[below] {A $\heartsuit$}
        }
        child {
                node[deck] {Second card}
                child {
                        node[end, label=below: {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[above] {$1$}
                        node[below] {A $\spadesuit$}
                }
                child {
                        node[end, label=below:  {$\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3}$}] {}
                        edge from parent 
                        node[above] {$0$}
                        node[below] {$\neg$A $\spadesuit$}
        }
                edge from parent
                node[above] {$\frac{2}{4}$}
                node[below] {$\neg$A}
        };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Apply [sloped] on a node by node basis instead of over the whole tikzpicture.

Comment: Alternatively, there is `[every label/.style={...}]`

Answer (score 1):

My try of using the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
    
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{makecell}    
\def\vcard#1{\makecell{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none}}
\xtdistance{35mm}{45mm}
\istrooto(0){\vcard{First\\card}}
  \istB{\frac14}[above,sloped]{A \spadesuit}[below,sloped]
  \istB{A \heartsuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14}[right]
  \istB{\neg A}[bl]{\frac24}[ar]
  \endist
\xtdistance{35mm}{20mm}
\istrooto(1)(0-1){\vcard{Second\\card}}
  \istB{\frac13}[above,sloped]{Q \spadesuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14\cdot\frac13}
  \istB{\frac13}[left]{Q \heartsuit}[above,sloped]{\frac14\cdot\frac13}
  \istB{\frac13}[above,sloped]{A \heartsuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14\cdot\frac13}
  \endist
\istrooto(2)(0-2){\vcard{Second\\card}}
  \istB{1}[l]{A \spadesuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14\cdot 1}
  \istB{0}[r]{\neg A \spadesuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14\cdot 0}
  \endist
\istrooto(3)(0-3){\vcard{Second\\card}}
  \istB{1}[l]{A \spadesuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14\cdot 1}
  \istB{0}[r]{\neg A \spadesuit}[below,sloped]{\frac14\cdot 0}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```